# fstab error and parse error when sudo mount -a

Tags: networking, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have made a network mount with password but get the error:

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 13 -- ignored
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line 14 -- ignored
```

and here is my `fstab` with the lines it is referring to:

```
    //unicph.domain/groupdir /media/groupdir cifs credentials=/home/fdm520/ .smbcredentials, iocharset=utf8 0 0
    //unicph.domain/users/fdm520 /media/fdm520 cifs credentials=/home/fdm520/ .smbcredentials, iocharset=utf8 0 0
```

what is wrong here

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; but you have (*it appears to me*) too many fields in your fstab entry... The space is a special character (ie. a *delimiter*), but it could also be your formatting is poor

Comment: Shouldn't `credentials=/home/fdm520/ .smbcredentials` be `credentials=/home/fdm520/.smbcredentials` ... removing the middle space?

Comment: ... and the space in `, iocharset` needs to go as well - options should be a strictly comma separated list